# Size of matplotlib plot in tkinter GUI depends on the primary monitor

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am getting some behaviour I do not understand when I put a matplotlib plot in a tkinter GUI on macOS. The size of the plot seems to depend on whether I have an external monitor plugged in or not.

If the external monitor (27" 1440p) is plugged in, the plot is small; if only the internal monitor (14" 3024x1964) is used, the plot is bigger.

External:
[image: Screenshot on external monitor]

Internal:
[image: Screenshot on internal monitor]

To show that the size of the plot is different, here is the GUI opened on the external monitor and dragged onto the internal monitor:
[image: Screenshot on internal, GUI opened on external]

I really do not understand what is going on here as the size of the figure (`fig_size` in inches) doesn't seem to correspond to anything, but the size of the plot is modulated by changing the `dpi` parameter.

I would like some way to keep the size of the plot consistent in regard to the rest of the GUI. Note that the size of the plot changes in relation to the 'WIDGET' label.

Minimal working example used to produce the screenshots:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame, object):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # Call baseclass constructor.
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)

        self.fig_size = (6.5, 4)
        self.dpi = 100
      
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
        self.notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

        ## Buid window with tabs ##

        width = 600
        height = 400

        self.main = tk.Frame(self.notebook, width=width, height=height)
        self.main.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.notebook.add(self.main, text='TAB 1')
 
        ttk.Style().map("TNotebook.Tab", foreground=[("selected", "#000000")])

        self.initialise_main(self.main)

    def initialise_main(self, tab):
        
        lbl = tk.Label(tab, text='WIDGET')

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(
            1, 1,
            figsize=self.fig_size,
            dpi=self.dpi,
        )

        self.line, = self.ax.plot([], [])  # empty graph
        self.ax.clear()

        self.GUIFig = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, tab)

        self.ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
        
        lbl.grid(row = 0, column=0)
        self.GUIFig.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application()
    app.master.title('MRE')
    app.mainloop()
```

NOTE: this example may not be completely miminimal but I wasn't sure if the OOP approach would change anything so I wanted to keep that consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had frame size changing on me, but to keep my plots within the frame, I get the dpi and set figure size relative to that and the frame size, and fill the frame with the plot.  I also restrict the frame from changing size by setting `self.frame2_fileplot.grid_propagate(False)`

```
# get frame size parameters (update frame parameters first)
self.frame2_fileplot.update()
dpi = self.root.winfo_fpixels('1i')
plotwidth = self.frame2_fileplot.winfo_width() / dpi
plotheight = self.frame2_fileplot.winfo_height() / dpi

# create plot
self.plot_figure_fileplot_main = Figure(figsize = (plotwidth, plotheight),
                                   dpi = dpi, frameon = False, tight_layout = True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It definitely looks like it should work, however I think macOS does something odd which means that `winfo_fpixels('1i')` returns the wrong resolution. On both monitors it returns 72 for me, but measuring pixels gives me 130 or 110 dpi on each monitor.
My imperfect workaround is to set the size of the graph to 0.4*screen resolution ( found using `winfo_screenwidth`) which gives more consistent results.